# React map "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, navbar

This below is Navbar.js and MenuItems.js Error is https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArTg3PgWw2jtgQ77RY23uF1tkSoA?e=YDsLlK
I pull data from array MenuItems.js and display with map in Navbar.js, error is saying  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined".
Why it occurs?

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { MenuItems } from './MenuItems'

class Navbar extends Component {
render () {
    return (
        <nav className="NavbarItems">
            <h1 className="NavbarLogo">React</h1>
        <div className="menu-icon">

        </div>
        <ul>
        {MenuItems.map((item, index) => {
            return (
         <li key={index}>
             <a className={item.cName} href={item.url}>
                {item.title}


</a>
                 </li>

            )
        })}
        
        </ul>
        </nav>
    )
}
```

}

export default Navbar;

menuitems.js

```
    const MenuItems = [
{
    title:'Home',
    url:'/',
    cName:'nav-links',
},
{
    title:'Services',
    url:'services',
    cName:'nav-links',
},
{
    title:'Products',
    url:'products',
    cName:'nav-links',
},
{
    title:'Contact Us',
    url:'contact-us',
    cName:'nav-links',
},
{
    title:'Sign Up',
    url:'sign-up',
    cName:'nav-links-mobile',
},
]
```

Comment: Missing `export default MenuItems`

Comment: To import you have to export. `export const MenuItems` as you are doing named import.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that's so easy. You just need to export the `MenuItems` from the `MenuItems.js` file just like that:

```
export const MenuItems =[{}, {}];
```